# Check a value exist in array in unity 3d

Tags: c#, arrays, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I have two script.

Script1
Script2

In Script1 i declared a arraylist it contains value 2, 4, 6, etc...

```
public static ArrayList aArray= new ArrayList();

function update(){
   if(bool1)
   {
      aArray.Add(i);
   }
}
```

I have to check a value 5 exist in arraylist from Script2.

**if value exists i have to get its key.**

How to get it?

Comment: No. One for camera. and another for character controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Contains. This code will detect if you have already the value in the ArrayList and will stop code from adding it a second time.

```
public static ArrayList aArray= new ArrayList();

function update()
{
   if(aArray.Contains(i)==false)
   {
      aArray.Add(i);
   }
}
```

If you want to remove a value it is just as easy as **aArray.Remove(i)**

Comment: I understood that by remove you meant "not to add". I have edited the question to tell you how to remove.

Comment: i just want remove array key also. Then only if remove 0 th value, automatically 1st value moves to 0..

Answer (score 3):

First, i would recommand using a generic `List<T>` instead of the non-generic `ArrayList`, which enables you to specify the type of objects that go into that list (for better type safety).
Also, declaring a variable `readonly` prevents you from accidently overwriting it, which is often the case with `List`s (after all, you can always just `Clear` them):

```
public static readonly List<int> items = new List<int>();
```

Now to answer your actual question, if you want to check if a value exists in the list, you can use the method `Contains`.
To check if the value does *not* exist, just put an `!` in front of the expression:

```
if (!Script1.items.Contains(i)) {
    // This will only execute if the list does not contain i.
    items.Add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understood correctly, Script1 is in your camera, and Script2 is in a Character. For the sake of this example we'll call them MainCamera and Character respectively.

Now, unless I understood wrong, you're trying to access an Array in Script1 from Script2. While the other answers are very much correct, unity3D has a bit of a workaround needed to access it.

Anyway, within Script2 use this:

```
if(GameObject.Find("MainCamera").GetComponent<Script1>().aArray.Contains(5))
{
   //Do your code here
}
```